# File paths aren't pulling in images or stylesheets

Tags: theming, .info

I'm sure I'm not the first person to run into this but I can't find another post about it.

I'm pretty new to drupal and I'm taking a swing at theming. I'm running into problems right out of the gate. I have my .info file set up and it is calling in two stylesheets and two javascript files. The stylesheets are not showing up on my site but the javascript files are...

also I have some place holder images within the template and no matter what I do with the file paths I can't get them to be pulled in either. I only bring this up because I feel like this is connected to my issue with the style sheets.

here is my .info file:

```
name = jonathansumner
description = A custom theme for jonathansumner.com
version = 1.0
core = 7.x
screenshot = screenshot.png

Stylesheet[all][] = ../css/bootstrap.css
Stylesheet[all][] = ../css/jbs.css

scripts[] = js/bootstrap.js
scripts[] = js/main.js

regions[header] = Header
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
regions[help] = Help
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Left sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Right sidebar
regions[footer] = Footer

features[] = logo
features[] = name
features[] = slogan
features[] = node_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_verification
features[] = favicon
features[] = main_menu
features[] = secondary_menu
```

My file stucture:

```
css [ 
  bootstrap.css
  jbs.css
  ]
js [
  bootstrap.js
  main.js
  ]
images [
  *images*
 ]
templates [
  page.tpl.php
 ]
jonathansumner.info
```

I've tried:

```
Stylesheet[all][] = ../css/bootstrap.css
Stylesheet[all][] = ../css/jbs.css
```

and:

```
Stylesheet[all][] = css/bootstrap.css
Stylesheet[all][] = css/jbs.css
```

and I have done the same with the images file paths within my html inside of page.tpl.php. I've been moving folders and files around for hours trying to get it to work and I haven't found an answer anywhere that solves this issue. I'm thinking I left something out of my .info file or maybe drupal can't handle directories or something. It's seams like this same set up works for other people though so I don't understand.

I have installed themes that work just fine so I don't think it is my installation causing it so it has to be user error of some type. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's `stylesheets` (plural)...

Comment: I think clive is right, just a matter of spelling, I have `stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/tab.css` in one that I'm working on right now, plural no capital.